# Determine bases of U1 + U2, U2 + U3, U1 + U2 + U3. Which of these sums are direct

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Three subspaces of R^4×1; U1 =[a], U2 =[{b,c}], U3 =[{b, a}]

a = (0, 1, 1, 0)^T , b = (1, 0, 0, 1)^T , c = (0, 1, 0, 0)^T.

Determine bases of U1 + U2, U2 + U3, U1 + U2 + U3. Which of these sums are direct?

I managed to do U1+U2;

U1+U2={a1*(0,1,1,0) + a2*(1,0,0,1) + a3*(0,1,0,0)}

The basis is {(0, 1, 1, 0)^T ,(1, 0, 0, 1)^T, (0, 1, 0, 0)^T)}

And the sum is direct because U1 ∩ U2 is the null vector.

For U2+U3 I got:

U2+U3= {a2*(1,0,0,1) a3*(0,1,0,0)+ a2*(1,0,0,1) + a1*(0,1,1,0)}

I don't know how to find a basis and if the sum is direct.

For U1+U2+U3 I can see that the sum isn't direct but again can't find a basis if there even is one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Next time you should use mathjax. As for your question, since $0\neq b\in U_2\cap U_3$, $U_2\cap U_3\neq \{0\}$, which implies that they are not the direct sum.

Comment: *All* vector spaces have bases! It is one of the basic facts about vector spaces you should have learned. And you do not have to go far to find bases for these. They have been effectively handed to you on a platter. Notice in your expression for $U_2 + U_3$, you have included the vector $b = (1,0,0,1)$ twice. You can combine them (you wrote the coefficient of each with the same symbol, "$a_2$", which was wrong since you were adding together arbitrary vectors in each of the spaces and there is no reason these arbitrary vectors would have the same $b$-component).